# disabled buttons still active on mobile safari

Tags: html, button, mobile-safari, javascript

Why does disabling buttons using mobile safari only grey them out and not actually disable them?

```
myButton.disabled = true;
myButton.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```

both of the above grey the button out but its ontouch event can still be fired. (It works as expected in all desktop browsers).

Am I making some kind of idiot mistake here or have Apple just decided that elements shouldn't be disabled on their touch devices?  Perhaps I am holding it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

tap on some other area of the page if  the button disabled on tap , it might be the hover effect of the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button")
buttons[0].setAttribute("disabled", true);
```

or all button elements disable attribute

```
for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) (function(button) {

    button.setAttribute("disabled", true);
}(button[i]))
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly the same as myButton.disabled = true;?
Anyway I tried it and it still doesn't work :-(